# Progress bar circle not center in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Im try to center in webpage this Progress bar circle but i cant do it , how can i center , please help me to fix that issue ,  ,im try to put that `text-center` but not work for me, please look at this image  you can understand that issue, 
thanks
[image: Look issue]

[/jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doggy2017/ohbhtog0/)

**html**

```
<div class="content-wrap">
<div>

<div class="progress-bar position text-center" data-percent="48" data-duration="1000" data-color="#6a6f77,#5fb756"><script>$(".progress-bar").loading()</script></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* Progress Bar */

.progress-bar {
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
.progress-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -webkit-transition: width .6s ease;
    -o-transition: width .6s ease;
    transition: width .6s ease;
}
.progress-bar div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.progress-bar div span {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 175px;
    height: 175px;
    width: 175px;
    left: 12.5px;
    top: 13.5px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: black;
}
.progress-bar .background {
    background-color: #b3cef6;
}
.progress-bar .rotate {
    clip: rect(0 100px 200px 0);
    background-color: #4b86db;
}
.progress-bar .left {
    clip: rect(0 100px 200px 0);
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #b3cef6;
}
.progress-bar .right {
    clip: rect(0 100px 200px 0);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: #4b86db;
}
@keyframes toggle {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
/*End of Progress Bar*/
```

Comment: Put the Progress bar Div inside a another DIV which has `.container-fluid`

Comment: Sir did you mean? i need the replace for  `content-wrap`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
.progress-bar {
        text-align: center;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        /* margin-left: 55px;*/
        margin-left: calc(100%/2 - 100px);
        margin-top: 65px;
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your whole code in [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: sir im added this

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Just add style:"text-align:center" in div, below the content-wrap div

Comment: Sir, not working `.content-wrap {text-align: center;}`

Comment: <div class="content-wrap">
<div style"text-align: center;">

<div class="progress-bar position text-center" data-percent="48" data-duration="1000" data-color="#6a6f77,#5fb756"><script>$(".progress-bar").loading()</script></div>
</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.progress-bar{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you are using multiple progress bar, then try this

```
.progress-bar{
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.on-parent-element{
    text-align: center
}
```

UPDATE-

here is working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/thesumit67/6jz40dfa/6/

You should add proper width on progress bar element, and remove float use inline-block instead.

In your fiddle you made two mistakes.

1. add jQuery before progress bar plugin.
2. use HTTPS to load external resources. ( check in your console )

Comment: Have you added it at the end of the styles, so that it can override previous values ?

Comment: sir, yeah i check not work, just try to fix it more than 3 h

Comment: sir im added this